# 'before' method is said to be undefined - spark java

Tags: java, spark-java

I am new to building web applications using spark java.

I am trying to use 'Before' filter but getting the below error. please help. I have pasted my code below.Bootstrap is my class having the main method.

> Error: "The method before is undefined for the type BootStrap"

```
public class BootStrap {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        ipAddress("localhost");
        port(3003);
        staticFileLocation("/public/html");
           before((request, response) -> {
                String user = request.queryParams("user");
                String password = request.queryParams("password");

                String dbPassword = usernamePasswords.get(user);
                if (!(password != null && password.equals(dbPassword))) {
                   halt(401, "You are not welcome here!!!");
                }
          });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the error you get.

Comment: This is the error message I am getting. "The method 'before' is undefined for the type BootStrap"

Comment: this looks unrelated to `apache-spark`. Could you correct the tags?

Comment: Hi, this issues is resolved. Thanks for your interest :) I am facing one more problem.  I am using ext js with spark Java in my web application. I'm doing a cross domain communication with proper CORS headers . Still I am getting the Error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl. Invalid HTTP status code 404". Below given is my spark code(in the next comment).  I don't know what's going wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: private static void enableCORS(final String origin, final String methods, final String headers) {
        before(new Filter() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
                response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
                response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                response.header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");              
            }
        });

    }

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just lacking to statically import Spark.*;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this helps, but according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) "Access-Control-Request-Method" is a request header, not a response header. That said, a 404 always shows that the resource you want to find does not exist. Are you sure your url is correct?